# How to create Gmail account using Selenium, I am having trouble with month and country drop downs

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to select Gmail month and country drop downs using select class, but it shows the error like

> Element should have been "select" but was "div"

I handled with actions class but not with select class. I tried with x path, id and class but I didn't get. I'm new to selenium.

Here is my code.

```
d.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount");
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    Select s=new Select(d.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")));
    s.selectByIndex(5);
    System.out.println("may slected...");
```

Comment: Error message says clearly, the HTML tag present in the browser console is not of element type 'Select'

Comment: I expect you'll find that if you are trying to create a large number of Gmail accounts on an automated basis, Google will shut you down pretty quickly, and will start to return server errors or apply IP blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see at [here](https://accounts.google.com/signup) the month drop down box is not actually a `select` element, you should try using `Actions` as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
Actions builder = new Actions(d);

WebElement selectMonth = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@title = 'Birthday']")));
builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)selectMonth).coordinates);      
selectMonth.click();

WebElement option = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text() = 'May']")));
builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)option).coordinates);   
option.click();
System.out.println("may slected...");
```

**Edited**: if you want to print all months try after clicking on `BirthMonth` dropdown as below:

```
WebElement selectMonth = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@title = 'Birthday']")));
builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)selectMonth).coordinates);      
selectMonth.click();

List<WebElement> allmonths = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("span#BirthMonth > div.goog-menu.goog-menu-vertical")));
for(WebElement el : allmonths) {
            System.out.println(el.getText())
}
```

Note however that if the purpose is to create large numbers of GMail accounts, Google will shut down these attempts pretty quickly, and will start to return server errors or apply IP blocks.

Comment: I tried with actions and i got the particular value from the drop down but i want to print all values from the drop down means from jan to dec

Comment: Thank you so much.. really am feeling happy.. @Saurabh Gaur

Comment: This is very helpful, but I do wonder whether it is wise to help beginners create automated accounts on the GMail site. One problem solved, lots of other problems created?

Comment: @halfer I'm sorry..but I didn't understand what do you mean by other problems created??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: it was a serious point made in jest. I'd be surprised if GMail accounts can be created automatically, especially if they are created from the same IP. However, if they can, what do you think they might be used for? Is it possible that someone wanting a large number of free email accounts might want to send spam?

Comment: @halfer I can't give you the answer for this case. beacuase I have never tried to create large number of free email accounts using automation.. I just provided the way to automate dropdown....:)

Comment: I think you are missing the point, perhaps I was too subtle! I was wondering if you might consider not helping potential spammers `:-)`. It is always _possible_ that the OP has another use in mind, I suppose...

Comment: Heh, it's too late now - the information has been provided, is available in the edit history, and it's not good to leave a non-answer. One to consider for the future instead? `:-)`

Comment: @halfer Ok I will keep it remember for the future...:)

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended or not possible to create using automated script like selenium. I would suggest to follow below steps to have multiple accounts & use inside input file.

Instead of creating multiple test account each time which is NOT possible per google policy.

Instead user strategy mentioned in http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20111201-0411

myaccount@gmail.com

myaccount+today_date_time@gmail.com